# objective C noob, retain or strong attribute on property does not match the property inherited

Tags: objective-c, collectionview

I am new to objective-c.  Trying to learn Storyboard.  I am getting following error in ViewController.h:

> 'retain (or strong)' attribute on property 'collectionView' does not
>   match the property inherited from 'UICollectionViewController'

Here is the code where it is complaining:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface ViewController : UICollectionViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>

    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;

    @end
```

thanks.

Comment: The UICollectionViewController already declares that property.  Since you're inheriting from it, you need not repeat the declaration.

Answer (score 3):

Your `collectionView` property is overriding a property inherited from `UICollectionViewController`, and `weak` doesn't match the inherited memory management semantic. Given that the property already exists, you can simply use it -- there's no need to redefine it.